# Assigning custom entities to other entities

Tags: entities

I will like to create a new entity, Job, in my site which can be assigned to other entities, such as Customers.  This would be similar to how Comments are related to Nodes.

In my particular example, the site is for a Local Electrician.  Customers are users (with a particular role). They will be assigned a Job by the administrator. The Job will have it's own attributes and fields like status date, available time slots, Assigned Engineer, etc.

On the Customers Profile, Jobs can be added, emailed, and SMS, similar to a CRM application.

How do I display a Customer Profiles with assigned Jobs attached?

Comment: I did a big rewrite on this, and narrowed it down to one question.  Once you figure this out, feel free to ask your second question (this answer may shed light on that one).

Comment: As a side note, if this is your first foray into Drupal, then using Nodes instead of custom Entities may make more sense.  It isn't the 100% proper way to do things, but custom entities bring along a lot of baggage that comes for free with nodes.

Comment: I agree with MPD. Just use nodes and an entity reference field